# How to make a \only<> like macro to be used at the end of line and escape it?

Tags: beamer, showexpl

I want to produce a tutorial showing code and its rendered output step by step.  The requirements are as follows.

- The source code should be kept simple.

  ```
  \LTXexample
    \begin{tikzpicture}%\only<1->
       \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);%\pause
       \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%\only<1->
  \endLTXexample
  ```

  is preferred to

  ```
  \LTXexample
   \only<1->{\begin{tikzpicture}}\pause
      \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);\pause
      \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
   \only<1->{\end{tikzpicture}}
  \endLTXexample
  ```
- Macros defined after `%`  must be escaped to allow overlays.
- `%` characters must NOT be printed in the formatted code because they will add complexity to the code and distract the reader's attention.

The output should be like the following but any `\only<1->{}` must be removed and the source code should be delimited only by `\only` like macro at the end instead of enclosing with cumbersome `\only<1->{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
    pos=r,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    numbers=none,
    preset=\centering,
    texcl=true,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Picture for Karl's students}
\LTXexample
\only<1->{\begin{tikzpicture}}\pause
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);\pause
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\only<1->{\end{tikzpicture}}
\endLTXexample

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\only<1->{...}` overlay specifications in your MWE? Removing them doesn't seem to change the output result and thus would considerably reduce the complexity of your problem as you don't want to have them displayed anyway.

Comment: @diabonas: There is no purpose in the given example, but it will be needed in other different examples.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the invisibility of the comment character `%`, an easy cheat is to render them in the background color (`commentstyle=\color{white}`). However, I have not yet understood what the purpose of the  `\only` commands shall be.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
    pos=r,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    numbers=none,
    preset=\centering,
    texcl=true,
    commentstyle=\color{white}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Picture for Karl's students}
\LTXexample
\begin{tikzpicture}%\pause
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);%\pause
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\endLTXexample

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The purpose as far as I understand is to be able to both increment the commands and the picture simultaneously. So it's kind of teaching TikZ in beamer with overlays. First TikZ environment appears then a line command while on the right hand side the picture gets updated with each command appearance.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a kind of contradictory situation here

- You use `texcl` to run code in comments
- but you want to hide the sign that opens the comment

On the good side: you only have to cheat the `listings.sty` into doing what you want.

A quick shot here would be to manipulate `listings` into thinking that a [TAB] precedes a comment, i.e. starting comments with a character already invisible.

On the other hand, you'd have to substitute tabs by spaces wherever you deliberately want to show code.

Comment: Indeed but how?